# Can I install/embed Wordpress on a 'single page'?

Tags: php, customization, css, page-template, blog-page

I'm building a website from scratch (PHP, jQuery) and want to have full control over the design, implementation, etc.

I want to install Wordpress so that when you go to a certain section of the site, the blog link in the menu bar, it takes you to root/blog/ but I don't want to have to use a template and design the rest of the site around it.
Obviously, I don't want the blog pages' design to be uniform with the rest of the site.

Surely this is possible right?

If not, then I'll settle for suggestions on a different, more appropriate technology but I think this should be possible.

Edit:
Is there is a way to set it up so that the user would use the wordpress.com site for admin and I simply integrate it with a PHP API. That would be fine also

Answer (score 1):

Include `wp-load.php` on your page and you'll have access to the WordPress API.

Comment: Is there a tutorial out there for this?

Comment: [this](http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages) is a quick how-to.

Comment: Thanks. Looks handy. Hope it's not too good to be true (too awkward to provide the typical Worpress installation functionalities)

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier than you might think.  Simply install WordPress into the /blog/ folder.  It will not affect the rest of your site.

Comment: But isn't there a default template with it's own menu, etc? 
Is there any tutorial out there for this?

Comment: Yes, there's a default template installed but you are free to make your own that matches your CSS/HTML if that's what you are looking to do.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a bit of hassle. Basically two separate similar designs (identical in look, similar in code [would have to use absolute paths, etc]). Had to it before for [SMF](http://simplemachinesforum.org/) and it was a pain.

Comment: Or, you could just let WordPress handle your entire site.  Changing the CSS for the blog would be easy to do.

Comment: Ok (not ideal at all), but does this hinder my existing jQuery and PHP?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, you should be able to integrate your jQuery and PHP just fine. You just need to make sure that you write your jQuery in 'No Conflict' mode.

Comment: I've never heard of `"no conflict mode"`. What do you think of @Milo 's solution?